# Is anyone else having issues with Google’s browser search?

Tags: google-search

For some reason, each time we do a search, Google displays the following message:

> We're sorry...... but your computer or
>   network may be sending automated
>   queries. To protect our users, we
>   can't process your request right now.

Is this just us, or are others experiencing the same problem?

Comment: Are you getting this error while browsing from cafe or your company?  I got similar error while from my company pd - Usually t out-going ip of all computers in intranet will be same, so google count it as automated queries...

Comment: If I could, I would vote to close as too localized.

Comment: @Ami I'd suppose it's not too localized. It is just an error message with a web app that the user's having trouble deciphering.

Comment: I've seen that error message myself. Just try again later and it should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message is most commonly seen when the IP address you're using is sending too many queries to Google, or when your browser's `user-agent` is not reporting correctly.

If you are in a large corporate environment which uses [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) to share a single real-world IP to the entire company, or sends all web traffic through a [proxy server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server), you stand a much greater chance of seeing this message.  In these situations, Google sees all of the corporate traffic as being from a single computer (IP Address).

If your security software likes to hide your `user-agent` header, you can also trigger this.  Google's terms of use explicitly disallow using software to search for you.  As a result, a nonexistent or unverified `user-agent` header can trigger this error.